# Is the switching workscreen still available on v14.04?

Tags: workspace-switcher

On the older versions I was able to switch from one of 4 screens in the work space. Is this not available in the new 14.04 version?

Comment: You do have to enable it first. "System Settings > Appearance - Behavior tab.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is also available.

You can do it by pressing <kbd>Super Key</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow keys</kbd> to go directly to any workspace you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can either click the Workspaces button on the launcher (above the trash), or press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to move between them, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> to take the current focused window with you.

[image]

Comment: The workspace button is not on the launcher, and when I hit ctrl + alt + arrow it does not do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Scott's Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/514841/is-the-switching-workscreen-still-available-on-v14-04/514844?noredirect=1#comment697388_514841